# "Unknown admin: ComponentInfo" when setting device owner within NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript

My current NativeScript requires the use of `startLockTask()`, Androids' kiosk mode that disables various features including the home menu buttons.

My current NativeScript application requires the app to be locked to the screen. I have tried 'pinning' the app and removing specific elements using `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`, `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` and `actionBarHidden = true;` but this doesn't seem to have the required effect.

It looks like I need to use `lockTaskMode` but to do so requires the app to also be the device own.

I've been following various guides and adapting to do this within a NativeScript application but when trying to `set-device-owner` via ADB, I am getting the following error when running the following command

`adb shell dpm set-device-owner org.app/.MyAdmin`

`Error: Unknown admin: ComponentInfo{org.app/org.app.MyAdmin}`

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.org"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyAdmin"
            android:description="@string/admin_description"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/admin" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### xml/admin.xml

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
        <disable-camera />
        <disable-keyguard-features />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: Have you defined `MyAdmin` that supposed be an implementation of `DeviceAdminReceiver`?

Comment: @Manoj I have tried but was unable to successfully extend this within a NativeScript way. If you have an example of how it should be done I'd be happy to give it a go

Comment: Here are some basics how you would write Java into JS - https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js and additionally you will have to use `@JavaProxy(YourPackageNameHere)` annotation to generate static Java class file for your receiver as you will have to register it in manifest. Read more about JavaProxy here - https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity

Comment: Thanks @Manoj but I've extended Android Java classes within both TypeScript and JavaScript perfectly fine at runtime without issues, it seems to be accessing and extending `receiver` that's the issue. The second link provided seems to only show extending the `application` and `activity` and unfortunately extending the receiver doesn't seem to be an option within a nativescript which is why I'm asking.

Comment: I posted the second link only for the purpose to understand `@JavaProxy`, otherwise you have everything you need in marshalling docs (the first link). Here is an example for simple SMS receiver - https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/can-anyone-share-sample-example-for-sms-receiver/3616/2 yours should be similar only that your base class will be admin receiver.

Comment: Thanks again for the links @Manoj but I've already got that and am still unable to set the application as the device admin. Currently I'm extending `android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver` but it's fruitless and I am unable to set the device admin as I'm still getting the save issue as in the original post. again, if you have an example working `DeviceAdminReceiver` that'll allow me to set the app as the device admin within NativeScript, that'd be somewhat helpful